# MongoDB $push method seems to be not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my User Schema, and I'm unable to add any posts.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 240,
    },
    sketchUri: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      min: 6,
      max: 64,
      required: true,
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
    },
    website: {
      type: String,
    },
    posts: [postSchema],
    profile_pic: {},
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And here is the code to add new posts:

```
const post = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { req.params.userId },
        {
          $push: {
            posts: {
              userId: req.user.id,
              content: req.body.thought,
              sketchUri: req.body.sketch,
            },
          },
        },
        { new: true }
      ).exec();
      res.json(post);
```

the `res.json(post)` statement here returns null.

Whenever I run this code, the backend returns a 200 status code, no errors are thrown inspite of using a try-catch block but the code isn't added anywhere in the database. Why is my `$push` function failing?

NOTE: Also, when I run the `findOneAndUpdate` function as follows, it returns the correct data, so the `userId` is correct.

```
const post = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ userId }).exec();
```

This is when I run the above code, but when I run it with `$push`, it returns null.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using `findOneAndUpdate()` and passing `req.params.userId`

You should be using `findByIdAndUpdate()` if you wish to pass the id as a parameter to find the user to update or change your code to be like:

```
const post = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { id: req.params.userId },
        {
          $push: {
            posts: {
              userId: req.user.id,
              content: req.body.thought,
              sketchUri: "aaaaaaa",
            },
          },
        },
        { new: true }
      ).exec();
      res.json(post);
```

I added `id: req.params.userId` if you can't see it

Answer (score 0):

So as we can notice that there is no field that you are matching the doc with at first place.
if we assume you are matching it with the default id that mongo is providing then please use the proper matching statement in the **findOneAndUpdate()** method.

```html
{id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}
```